# Spark does not use correct configuration from core-site.xml

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, hadoop3

When I try to read a parquet file from a specified location like /test with spark.read.parquet() i get an error saying file://test does not exist. When I add the core-site.xml as a resource in code with

```scala
sc.hadoopConfiguration.addResource(new Path(<path-to-core-site.xml>))
```

it does look in the hdfs. However I don't want to add the resource in code. My question is how do I make sure spark reads the core-site.xml and uses hdfs as default file system.

I've setup an ubuntu 18.04.2LTS server with hadoop 3, spark 2.4.2 and yarn as resourcemanager in a virtual machine. I've configured the core-site.xml with fs.defaultFS set to hdfs://localhost:9000.
I've also configured the HADOOP_CONF_DIR in the bash file.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of options
1. Make sure that core-site.xml is available in driver's classpath. This way the core-site.xml will get loaded automatically.
2. If only setting the default filesystem uri is the requirement, we can set this in `spark-defaults.conf` or in the `SparkConf` object created for the application using `spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS` and set its value to `hdfs:///`

Answer (score 1):

Well its a generic question with many possible answers.
Ill try to answer as best as I can :
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#inheriting-hadoop-cluster-configuration
It is explained in the link you can set the enviroment variable HADOOP_CONF_DIR to the dir that contains the core-site.xml and as long as you dont override it in spark-env.sh or something it should work.

BTW are you sure you did an export on the HADOOP_CONF_DIR because I know from experience it works with Spark 2.4.2 so if you think the core-site isnt loaded its probably because you didnt define the variable correctly or maybe your spark-env.sh masks your previous definition.